# Access to the map with a tuple key on partial key

Tags: go

I have a map with tuple key {int, string}:

```
    NWKey struct {
        deviceId      int64
        interfaceType string
    }

    m = make(map[NWKey]int, 0)
```

I need to get map's elements for partial key, something like this {int, *}, where * means this part of key isn't matter. Is it possible in goland to do it& If yes please explain how to do it.

Comment: Please, update your question and change the tag to `go`. Otherwise, Go folks cannot see it. GoLand is the IDE for Go development.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with just a direct lookup. One problem is that there could exist multiple keys with the same `deviceId`.

Instead what you would need to do is to iterate over your map and find the with the correct id. For example:

```golang
wantedId := 532

for key, value := range m {
  if key.deviceId == wantedId {
    // Do what you want to do here
  }
}
```

However, this does partly remove the use case for maps. You could reconsider refactoring your struct to only have the deviceId as key (`map[int64]int`), but this might not work for you.